# insertBefore() an iframe jquery problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have to handle content from a WISIWYG where the user could potentially imbed a youtube video.

I need to search the container that the WISIWYG is outputted to for any iframe, and then wrap that iframe in a `<div class="video-wrapper">` tag. Heres what I've tried:

```
        $('div.content').each(function () {
            var iframe = $(this).find('iframe');

            $('<div class="video-wrapper">').insertBefore(iframe);
            $('</div>').insertAfter(iframe);

        });
```

This doesnt work and will end up just adding the `div` (including closing tag) right before the iframe.

Ideas?

Comment: You can't add partial HTML like that... it's invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) - you can't add partial HTML like that, it's invalid:

```
var iframe = $(this).find('iframe');
iframe.wrap("<div class='video-wrapper' />");
```

Comment: Points go to you good sir since you were the first. Thanks a lot! I didnt know about that method (never had to use it before).

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `$.wrap`. See: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
$('div.content').each(function () {
    $(this).find('iframe').wrap('<div class="video-wrapper"></div>');
});
```

Comment: maybe `$('div.content iframe').wrap('<div class="video-wrapper"></div>');`